# Python: What is the difference between df[‘Col’].apply(lambda row: len(row)) and df.apply(lambda row: len(row[‘Col’]), axis=1)?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['user1', 'Hey whats up I am Rob', 73],
                    ['user2', 'Hey whats up I am Bob', 44],
                    ['user3', 'Hey whats up I am a Snob', 12]],
                    columns=['User', 'Text', 'Age'])

#Method 1
df['TextLen'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda row: len(row))

#Method 2
df['TextLen2'] = df.apply(lambda row: len(row['Text']), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   User                      Text  Age  TextLen  TextLen2
0  user1     Hey whats up I am Rob   73       21        21
1  user2     Hey whats up I am Bob   44       21        21
2  user3  Hey whats up I am a Snob   12       24        24
```

**What is the difference between Method 1 and Method 2?**

**Which is more Pythonic / Which should I be using on large datasets?**

Comment: both methods have no big difference in execution

Comment: Both suggestions are not Pythonic. The right one is `df['Text'].str.len()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **%%timeit** magic in **jupyter notebook**, I timed each of your two methods. **Method 1 is much faster than method 2.**

I have also found that **list comperehension** is twice as fast as Method 1. See Method 3 below...

**Method 1 (FASTER)**

```
%%timeit
df['TextLen'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda row: len(row))
#434 µs ± 6.73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Method 2 (SLOWER)**

```
%%timeit
df['TextLen2'] = df.apply(lambda row: len(row['Text']), axis=1)
#1.24 ms ± 19.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Method 3 (FASTEST)**

```
%%timeit
df['TextLen3'] = [len(i) for i in df['Text']]
#202 µs ± 4.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Method 4 (FAST but READABLE)**

```
%%timeit
df['TextLen4'] = df['Text'].str.len()
#525 µs ± 53.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

I used the sample example data as you to run these tests.

*Edit 1: I tried a third method and thought it was faster before I realized it did not work. I have removed it from the answer.*

*Edit 2: I tried a list comprehension method (Method 3) and determined that it worked, so I have added it to the answer*

*Edit 3: Added in the method (Method 4) suggested in the comments on the OP*

Comment: Excellent - not only did you answer my question, but you showed me how to test it in the future! Was wondering if there was a way to test in Jupyter.

Comment: Glad to help :) Just updated the answer with a third method! Jupyter has really great options for testing, so check them out!

Comment: I also facing the same prob using lambda where the column is int and have a null value so giving me error 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
[
df['variety_name'] = df.apply(lambda row: variety_name(row)[0], axis=1)]